# Extension of pluriharmonic functions

Tags: several-complex-variables, complex-geometry

Suppose $M$ is a complex manifold and $\Omega$ a (edit: bounded) pseudoconvex domain in $M$. Let $u:M\setminus\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be a pluriharmonic function. Is it true that $u$ has a pluriharmonic extension to $M$? edit: $dim_{\mathbb{C}}(M)\geq 2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your condition $\dim M>2$ does not save the situation: you can have many counterexamples
with $M=M'\times C^n$ where $\dim M'=1$ and your functions are independent of the second
variable. And in dimension $1$ you certainly have plenty of pluriharmonic (=harmonic) functions which do not extend anywhere.

Comment: Good point. I forgot to add that $\Omega$ should be a \textit{bounded} pseudoconvex domain. 

Comment: And by pseudoconvex I mean strictly pseudoconvex.

Comment: How about $\Omega=B(0,1)\subset \mathbb C^2$ and $u(z,w)=Re(e^{1/(z-1)})$? (cf remark of Alexandre) 

Comment: Yes, if $B(0,1)=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|\leq 1\}\times \mathbb{C}$ then I agree. But I don't think $u$ is pluriharmonic on $M\setminus B(0,1)$ if $B(0,1)$ is the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes; if you want consider $\Omega = B(0, 1/2)$; by uniqueness of the pluriharmonic extension (ph functions are real analytic), $u$ won't extend to $\mathbb C^2$ either.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that I misunderstood your question; I thought that $u$ was only defined on $\Omega$. 

In fact, if $M\setminus \Omega$ has $b_1=0$, then every pluriharmonic function on $M\setminus \Omega$ is the real part of a holomorphic function; so $u=Re(f)$ for $f \in \mathcal O(M\setminus \Omega)$. Now, if $M\setminus \Omega$ is connected, Hartog's extension theorem tells you that $f$ extends (uniquely) to $M$, and then $Re(f)$ extends $u$ has a pluriharmonic function. 


Comment: Thanks! And to apply Hartog's extension theorem I need to know that $\Omega$ is pseudoconvex, right? 

Comment: No, not even. You just need $\Omega$ relatively compact, and $M\setminus \overline{\Omega}$ connected. (btw, you should have defined $u$ on $M\setminus \overline{\Omega}$ only if you want to make sense of pluriharmonicity)

Comment: I'm pretty sure one has to make an additional assumption about $\bar{\Omega}$ if $M\neq \mathbb{C}^n$ (or not Stein etc.). For example, if $M$ is compact and $\bar{\Omega}$ is the complement of some small (connected) open set in $M$ then there are plenty of non-constant holomorphic functions on $M\setminus \bar{\Omega}$ that do not extend to $M$.

     

Comment: Yes you are right of course; I just had in mind the case where $M$ is a domain in $\mathbb C^n$. My point was just that the assumptions on $\Omega$ should not be too restrictive like pseudoconvexity e.g.; but on $M surely!

Comment: Well, thanks again for you answer. What I was missing is the fact that $b_1=0$ implies that any pluriharmonic function is the real part of a holomorphic function. But now it's clear. 

Answer (score 3):

In contrast, for plurisubharmonic functions and their subextensions the situation is more difficult:
In: Fornæss, John Erik; Sibony, Nessim: Plurisubharmonic functions on ring domains. Complex analysis (University Park, Pa., 1986), 111–120, Lecture Notes in Math., 1268, Springer, Berlin, 1987 (MR0907057), 
the authors consider plurisubharmonic (psh) function on $B\setminus K$, where $B$ is a ball in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $K$ is a polynomially convex set. They give  the following counterexamples: one is a smooth psh function on $B\setminus K$, $K$ a polydisk,  which does not have a psh subextension to $B$; another one is a discontinuous psh function on $B\setminus K$, $K$ a smaller ball, which does not have a psh subextension to $B$. There is also earlier work about psh functions that cannot be extended across a pseudoconvex set: 
Bedford, Eric; Burns, Dan
Domains of existence for plurisubharmonic functions.
Math. Ann. 238 (1978), no. 1, 67–69 (MR0510308).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure I understand the counterexample correctly. Isn't $u$ just plurisubharmonic on $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus \Omega$? 

Comment: My previous example was confusing, so best thing is to forget it. Anyway, @Henri sketched an answer.